# LG Optimus 4X HD - unlock bootloader?

Tags: bootloader, lg-optimus-4x

I have just rooted the LG Optimus 4X HD using instructions I found at [How to root the LG Optimus 4X (LG-P880)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/40620/16575)

I now need to unlock the bootloader, but for some reason the command `adb reboot oem-unlock` does't seem to do what it should. All it does is reboot the device, and it boots normally again. Apparently it should boot to a screen asking if I want to unlock the bootloader.

Any ideas why this is not working for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was my post (actually, with the JB update, rooting got even easier) – so maybe I can help you a second time:

### Initial note:

**IMPORTANT:** Unlocking the bootloader on the O4X only works with Firmware V20 (approved for V20A and V20B; as OP hjust upgraded using the official tools, most likely V20C works as well). To check what firmware you're on, go to *Settings › About Phone › Software Information* – last entry there should read "Software version", starting with "P880XXY". If XX is a 20, you're fine; if it's a 10, you'll need to upgrade your device first.

### Official approach

XDA Developers has [a post describing the procedure](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2224020). Requirements are similar to the ones in my "rooting answer", so you should already meet them. According to that "official LG procedure", the steps are as follows:

1. fully charge your device to 100%
2. connect your phone in LG software mode (or simply enable [usb-debugging](/questions/tagged/usb-debugging))
3. run: `adb reboot oem-unlock`

### Alternative approach #1

As that failed for you (and not only you, others report that as well), let's look for an alternative approach. In [another thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2263627), XDA features an unlock tool for our O4X. I just found this now when looking for a different post – and wondered about the "relock" part: AFAIK, the O4X uses FUSEs for the lock status. Once blown, there's no way back. Obviously, that XDA member found a way around that (using a boot-loader hack): "by using this program you have 16 chances to unlock relock bootloader before all fuses blown".

### Alternative approach #2

That's rather a "last resort" if everything else fails: Blow all the related FUSEs directly. Again [described in an XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2245836) (note the original/initial post has some errors, so here's a corrected version):

1. open a terminal (or use `adb shell`)
2. make yourself root (run `su`)
3. get the actual FUSE state by executing `cat /sys/firmware/fuse/odm_reserved > /data/local/tmp/odm_reserved`
4. in the created file, change the line `0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 00000040000000c8`
5. write it back: `cat /data/local/tmp/odm_reserved > /sys/firmware/fuse/odm_reserved`

While this directly blows the FUSEs, it has one advantage over the "official method": No data lost, as no [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset) is performed – a fact it most likely shares with "alternative approach #1" ;)

### Check results

Whatever approach you took: You can check the results in "Hidden Menu" (dial `3845#*880#`).

Comment: i should have also mentioned, in the hidden menu there is no bootloader status option

Comment: I've just checked: It is there ("Bootloader Unlock Check"). May I ask which firmware version you're on? I'm afraid all the above is only valid for v20 – not having the entry in HiddenMenu points to a v10 firmware.

Comment: I'll need to check in Monday as I don't have the device with me now. Where do I check?

Comment: *Settings › About Phone › Software information* should reveal it. Last entry there should be "Software version", starting with "P880XXY". If the XX is a 20, you're fine – if it's a 10, you'd first need to upgrade. Another indicator: Which Android version is it running? v10 = 4.0.3, v20 = 4.1.2. In hindsight: If my rooting answer worked for you, your device is most likely still running v10...

Comment: android 4.0.3
LG-P880-V10h-NOV-19-2012

Comment: Thought so (that was what mine was running until a few weeks ago). No chance to unlock your bootloader without upgrading to v20 before AFAIK. Mine is on V20C now. Battery consumption is horrible compared to V10H :( I'm considering to try a custom ROM, reports seem to indicate better battery time then...

Comment: OK, i've updraded it to 4.1.2 using the LG upgrade tool.
i've rooted it again (using your initial instructions).
now when i go to unlock the bootloader, the "adb reboot oem-unlock" command still doesn't work.
this time it appeared to just turn the device off.

Comment: OK, i had to use alternate approach #1 to unlock the bootloader.. the device is now reporting it as unlocked

Comment: Glad to read it finally worked out! You might consider accepting the answer then (click the check-mark next to it), as it solved your issue. This way others can easily recognize the problem has a solution :)

Comment: CyanogenMod 11 is a big laggy!!!